# XSL show attribute name

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

So, using that

```
<xsl:for-each select="./@*">
   [<xsl:value-of/><xsl:value-of select="."/>]
</xsl:for-each>
```

I can iterate over attribute values.
But I want to see attribute names too.

I want see a table:
attr1 - val1
attr2 - val2
attr3 - val3
...

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that using [`name()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-name) or [`local-name()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-local-name):

```
<xsl:for-each select="./@*">
    [<xsl:value-of select="name()"/><xsl:value-of select="."/>]
</xsl:for-each>
```