# not(@attribute) test not working in JDom XSL transform?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, jdom, xalan

I have a piece of an XSLT stylesheet that works as expected using xsltproc but produces a different output in my actual application, where the transform is applied via `org.jdom.transform.XSLTransformer` (jdom 1.0), I believe using Xalan.

Stylesheet snippet (this is part of [a larger template](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-4_x/dspace/config/crosswalks/DIM2DataCite.xsl#L34) that starts like this: `<xsl:template match="/dspace:dim[@dspaceType='ITEM']">`):

```
<xsl:if test="//dspace:field[@mdschema='dc' and @element='rights']">
  <rightsList>
    <xsl:if test="//dspace:field[@mdschema='dc' and @element='rights' and not(@qualifier) and @language='*']">
      <rights>
        <xsl:if test="//dspace:field[@mdschema='dc' and @element='rights' and @qualifier='uri' and @language='*']">
          <xsl:attribute name="rightsUri">
            <xsl:value-of select="//dspace:field[@mdschema='dc' and @element='rights' and @qualifier='uri' and @language='*']"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="//dspace:field[@mdschema='dc' and @element='rights' and not(@qualifier) and @language='*']" />
      </rights>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//dspace:field[@mdschema='dc' and @element='rights' and not(@language='*')]" />
  </rightsList>
</xsl:if>
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="//dspace:field[@mdschema='dc' and @element='rights' and not(@language='*')]">
    <rights><xsl:value-of select="." /></rights>
</xsl:template>
```

XML snippet:

```
<dim:dim dspaceType="ITEM" xmlns:dim="http://www.dspace.org/xmlns/dspace/dim">
  <dim:field element="rights" language="en_NZ" mdschema="dc">Actual text redacted</dim:field>
  <dim:field element="rights" language="*" mdschema="dc">Attribution 3.0 New Zealand</dim:field>
  <dim:field element="rights" qualifier="uri" language="*" mdschema="dc">http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/nz/</dim:field>
</dim:dim>
```

With xsltproc, this produces

```
<rightsList>
  <rights rightsUri="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/nz/">Attribution 3.0 New Zealand</rights>
  <rights>Actual text redacted</rights>
</rightsList>
```

In my application, this produces

```
<rightsList>
  <rights>Actual text redacted</rights>
  <rights>Attribution 3.0 New Zealand</rights>
  <rights>http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/nz/</rights>
</rightsList>
```

So to me it looks like the `not(@qualifier)` bit doesn't work using jdom.

I'd appreciate any insight into what's going on here and how I might change the stylesheet to get the same result in my application that I currently get via xsltproc.

Edited to add: just in case it makes any difference, the stylesheet starts out as

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:dspace="http://www.dspace.org/xmlns/dspace/dim"
            xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common"
            xmlns="http://datacite.org/schema/kernel-3"
            extension-element-prefixes="exslt"
            exclude-result-prefixes="exslt"
            version="1.0">
```

and also includes this template:

```
<!-- Don't copy everything by default! -->
<xsl:template match="@* | text()" />
```

**See my answer below** the XML structure is actually different from what I thought it was, so the problem wasn't in the XSL after all.

Comment: What if you replace `not(@language='*')` by `@language != '*'`?

Comment: @CoDEmanX I changed `//dspace:field[@mdschema='dc' and @element='rights' and not(@language='*')]` to `//dspace:field[@mdschema='dc' and @element='rights' and @language!='*']` in both XSL snippets (3rd line from bottom in the longer snippet). With that change, the transform via the application produces an empty `rightsList` element. So it looks like the `not(...)` overall somehow isn't working, or the asterisk is at fault, or something?

Comment: How should we place the first `xsl:if` snippet to get the wrong result? Your error may be caused by the `xsl:template` surrounding the `xsl:if` that you forgot to copy in your question. I placed it inside `<xsl:template match="/">` (assuming) and with Xalan, xsltproc and .NET Xslt I get the same results.

Comment: A wild guess, but try running it using Apache Xerces as your XML parser rather than the parser built in to the JDK. Inexplicable bugs involving attribute values sometimes go away when you do that.

Comment: @MichaelKay I can't change the environment this is running in in my application, sorry I should have mentioned this.

Comment: `'*'` shouldn't cause any trouble, because the asterisk is surrounded by single quotes. `*` would be different. You can still try `'&#42'` of course.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. In my answer I assume a few things (prior to your edit), the rewrite may help to get to the cause of your issue, or just resolve it ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from solving your original problem, let's have a quick look at how to reorganize your code.

You use a lot of `//foo` expressions. Starting an expression with `//foo` means "search the whole document, at any level, for the element with the name `foo`". Apart from this being a potentially expensive operation, this often has unwanted side effects and makes your code hard to read, because it requires you to specify each element uniquely, leading to a lot of duplicated code.

You also use a lot of `xsl:if`, but in XSLT, it is hardly ever necessary to use if-statements (an exception in XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 being when you deal with something other than nodes). In almost all cases, you can replace an `xsl:if` with a simple `xsl:apply-templates`.

That said, let's have a look how we can rewrite your code to get the same effect and have less chance for error:

```
<xsl:if test="//dspace:field[@mdschema='dc' and @element='rights']">
    <rightsList>
      .....
```

Is similar to having a matching template as follows (assuming you have a throw-away template for uninteresting nodes):

```
<xsl:template match="dspace:dim[dspace:field[@mdschema='dc' and @element='rights']]">
    <rightsList>
```

This says: if you encounter a `dim` element with any `field` element that has those properties set, then output `<rightsList>`.

Then you have:

```
<xsl:if test="//dspace:field[@mdschema='dc' and @element='rights' and not(@qualifier) and @language='*']">
    <rights>
```

Which is precisely equivalent to the following apply-template expression (assuming a matching template with it):

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="dspace:field[@mdschema='dc' and @element='rights' and not(@qualifier) and @language='*']" />
```

Here we find that a little bit below that, we have an almost equivalent expression, this time with `not(@language='*')`. So let's see if we can get rid of those duplicate expressions altogether.

First, let's go back a bit and have a look at what you were doing:

- If anywhere any "dc" and "rights", then create a `<rightsList>`
- If anywhere any of these have do not have a qualifier but have a language "*", create `<rights>`
- Inside this, create an attribute `rightsUri` if anywhere any qualifier has value "uri" and language "*", set its value to the first such you find
- After this `<rights>` element (there can be at most one of them in your current structure), create a list of `<rights>` for each field element with language "*"

If this is correct, then this can be rewritten as follows:

```
<xsl:template match="dspace:dim[dspace:field[@mdschema='dc' and @element='rights']]">
    <xsl:variable name="adjusted">
        <xsl:copy-of select="dspace:field[@mdschema='dc' and @element='rights']"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <rightsList>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($adjusted)/*[not(@qualifier) and @language='*'][1]" mode="noquali"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($adjusted)/*[not(@language='*')]" />
    </rightsList>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dspace:field" mode="noquali">
    <rights>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/dspace:field[@qualifier='uri' and @language='*'][1]" mode="uri"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </rights>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dspace:field" mode="uri">
    <xsl:attribute name="rightsUri" select="." />
</xsl:template>

<!-- matching anything else -->
<xsl:template match="dspace:field">
    <rights><xsl:value-of select="." /></rights>
</xsl:template>
```

The [`exsl:node-set`](http://exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/index.html) function is supported by just about every XSLT 1.0 processor, just add the namespace `xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"` to your `xsl:stylesheet` declaration.

Note that I added a few times `[1]` to the select-expressions. While you don't do that in your code, your current code has the same effect, but if you use apply-templates, if you encounter multiple matches, you have to specify that you are only interested in the first match.

I think your code can be further simplified, but I wanted to make sure that the logic remains exactly the same. As you can see, the end result is without any `//`. However, you do see one `/`, which is now pointing to the root of the node-set, which conveniently only has the nodes you are interested in: the ones with schema "dc" and "rights" element attributes, so we do not have to repeat that expression over and over again.

You may try this rewrite and see if it helps with your current bug, otherwise I'll gladly to help you further.

### Edit

After your edit, your original context item will have been `dspace:dim` already. If you don't mind always outputting `<rightsList>` (even if it ends up empty), you can simply replace my first template match pattern above with your existing `dspace:dim` pattern.

Comment: Cheers mate, however I'm working within an existing document that I want to change as little as possible. So I don't think this is the way forward unfortunately.

Comment: @schweerelos: refactoring of unreadable code is always a good thing, I think. But anyway, if your code is larger than you showed, try your example input with the minimized XSLT and see if you still get different outputs. If not, you can work your way back from there. Otherwise you may never see the wood for the trees...

Comment: normally I'd be with you on the refactoring, however (and I should probably have said so) I'm customising a [stylesheet](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-4_x/dspace/config/crosswalks/DIM2DataCite.xsl) in a local install of an open source product, so I want to avoid major changes if at all possible to not put too many obstacles into future upgrades. But I'll try your variable/mode approach and see what happens.

Comment: @schweerelos fair enough, but if it is open source, I am sure they will welcome a good refactoring ;). Just had a look: looks like this was machine-generated code, with XML Spy or something similar. It is terrible to humanly read...

Comment: I'm going to mark this answer as the accepted one, even though you actually got the logic not-quite-right and the problem ended up being wrong assumptions about the XML on my part. But people responding to my question couldn't really know that and rewriting the templates did eventually get me to figure out that there was no issue with the "not" operator nor the attribute behaviour.

Comment: @schweerelos: thanks. Yes, I made some assumptions based on the original code, but I wasn't aware of the _intent_ of the code, nor how it potentially related to the larger picture. Glad rewriting it solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Duh. Forest/trees indeed. Even though the language attribute is called "language" pretty much everywhere else in the application (see also, the XML snippet I gave), it is actually called "lang" in the XML that my stylesheet operates on - I finally gave in and used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3355629/72625) to be sure what the XML structure is. Surprise!

Anyway, I followed the advice [Abel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/111575/abel) gave in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32215953/72625) in part and simplified the templates for this particular case quite a bit. I now just have

```
<xsl:if test="dspace:field[@mdschema='dc' and @element='rights']">
    <rightsList>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="dspace:field[@mdschema='dc' and @element='rights']"/>
    </rightsList>
</xsl:if>
```

in the big template, plus a couple of custom ones:

```
<xsl:template match="dspace:field[@mdschema='dc' and @element='rights']">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@qualifier='uri'"/>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <rights>
                <xsl:if test="@lang='*'">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="//dspace:field[@mdschema='dc' and @element='rights' and @qualifier='uri' and @lang='*'][1]" mode="rightsURI"/>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </rights>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dspace:field[@mdschema='dc' and @element='rights' and @qualifier='uri' and @lang='*']" mode="rightsURI">
    <xsl:attribute name="rightsURI"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```